# Nested select statements in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing SQL query that works fine in SQL Server, that I would like to make work in MySQL. I have cleaned it up a bit, and fiddled with the back-ticks for column / table names, etc. but cannot get it to work.

Here is the statement in question:

```
SELECT `EmployeeID`
FROM `Employee`
WHERE
(
   (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS A
      FROM `TimeClock`
      WHERE (`EmployeeID` = `Employee.EmployeeID`)
         AND (`InOut` = 'True')
   ) > (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS B
      FROM `TimeClock` AS `TimeClock_1`
      WHERE (`EmployeeID` = `Employee.EmployeeID`)
         AND (`InOut` = 'False')
   )
)
```

This should return any `EmployeeID`'s that have more `InOut = True` than `InOut = False` in the `TimeClock` table.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the error you getting ?

Comment: Error: `Unknown column 'Employee.EmployeeID' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide you with the `EmployeeId` values where there are more values of `InOut` True than False

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT tc.EmployeeID
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN tc.InOut = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) AS InOutTrue
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN tc.InOut = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) AS InOutFalse
   FROM TimeClock AS tc
   GROUP BY tc.EmployeeId
) AS t ON e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
WHERE t.InOutTrue > t.InOutFalse
```

The two alternatives I came up with show similar performance on my **VERY SMALL** unindexed test data.  I would recommend you test them against your own data to see if they make any difference:

This one is pretty much the same, but using total record count instead of InOutFalse.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT tc.EmployeeID
      , COUNT(1) AS RecordCount
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN tc.InOut = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) AS InOutTrue
   FROM TimeClock AS tc
   GROUP BY tc.EmployeeId
) AS t ON e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
WHERE t.InOutTrue > RecordCount - t.InOutTrue
```

I am not sure if MySQL will require the `CAST` I used here, but SQL Server did. (That is what I tested these with)  It could not perform a `SUM` on a `BIT` column.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN TimeClock AS tc ON e.EmployeeId = tc.EmployeeId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
HAVING SUM(CAST(tc.InOut AS INT)) > (COUNT(1) - SUM(CAST(tc.InOut AS INT)))
```

If all three perform similarly, it then comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Humm, I get zero rows back on a table that I know EmployeeID 1 has more InOut's true than false... (sample data has 10 True, 9 False)

Comment: Reducing the code above to just the inner select, and running that returns employeeid's with zero for bock InOutTrue and InOutFalse, if that helps...

Comment: @Fuginator What is the DataType for InOut?  Is it actually a string, or a bool?  Also, are there any other values for InOut than `True` or `False`?

Comment: Changed `'True'` and `'False'` in the `CASE` statments to `1` and `0` - everything works!

Comment: @Fuginator There is a cleaner way to approach this then, give me a few minutes

Comment: @Fuginator I updated my answer with two alternatives.  Glad I could help.

Comment: The final solution works, after removing the `CAST` statements.  Can you please clarify the purpose of the `(COUNT(1) - ...)` on the RHS of the `>` operator? I would have thought just one count greater than the other should work, however it seems the `COUNT(1)` is rather needed! **Thanks again**

Comment: BTW, all three execute in 0.000 Sec on a table w\ 30,000 records, according to MySQL Workbench :)

Comment: Nevermind, got it, the `SUM(tc.InOut)` is _just the true's_ , `Count(1)` being _Total_ (duh), just the (in) being greater than (total - in) works.  Smart man.